# How can I get a list of all users that belong to a specific department from Active Directory?

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, active-directory, directoryservices

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to get a list of all users and groups that belong to a specific department (entered by the user) from Active Directory using VB.Net and DirectoryServices.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're on .NET 2.0, that's probably as good as it gets. What you could do is add the "department" criteria to your search filter - that way, you'd leave it up to AD to do the filtering by department:

```
Private Sub GetUsersByDepartment(ByVal department as String)
  Dim deGlobal As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(ADPath, ADUser, ADPassword)
  Dim ds As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(deGlobal)

  ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(department=" & department & "))"
  ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree

  For Each sr As SearchResult In ds.FindAll
    Dim newDE As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(sr.Path)
    If Not newDE Is Nothing Then
          *Do Something*
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

That would certainly help - I hope as a C# programmer, I didn't screw up your VB code!

The LDAP filter basically allows you to have any number of conditions inside an "anded" bracket (the `(&....)` around your two conditions - you can easily extend that to three conditions as I did).

If you have a chance to move up to .NET 3.5, there's a new namespace called `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` available, which offers much better and more "intuitive" approaches for handling users, groups, computers, and searching.

Check out the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) to learn more about this.

What you can do is e.g. "search by example", so you could create a `UserPrincipal` and set those properties you want to filter on, and then do a search by that object as a "template" almost:

```
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(adPrincipalContext);
user.Department = "Sales";

PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher(user);

PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = pS.FindAll();

// now you could iterate over the search results and do whatever you need to do
```

Quite neat indeed ! But only on .NET 3.5, unfortunately.... but wait - that's just a service pack on top of .NET 2, really :-)

Comment: That works like a charm, marc_s. Much appreciated! Trust me, there are *several* features of .NET 3.5 I would like to take advantage of (this being one of them). I appreciate the improved solution and the quick tip on DirectoryServices. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's what I came up. It seems to work, but I'm certainly open to suggestions or improved solutions.

```
Private Sub GetUsersByDepartment(ByVal department as String)
  Dim deGlobal As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(ADPath, ADUser, ADPassword)
  Dim ds As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(deGlobal)

  ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
  ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree

  For Each sr As SearchResult In ds.FindAll
    Dim newDE As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(sr.Path)
    If Not newDE Is Nothing Then
      If newDE.Properties.Contains("department") Then
        If newDE.Properties("department")(0).ToString = department Then
          *Do Something*
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```